# Remove Tax from PDF Invoice (HELP!)

Tags: tax, invoice, pdf

I've been searching around and struggling to find a conclusive answer to this.

I've followed the steps mentioned here:
http://nsmchami.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/magento-remove-tax-from-invoice/

Which has removed the "Tax" header in the column, but it's still displaying the price, like so:
[image: Tax header removed but value still displays]

So the question is how can I remove this price from the Invoice PDF?

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the model `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default` and remove this

```
    // draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed'  => 495,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );
```

the model `Mage_Bundle_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice` and remove this:

```
            $tax = $order->formatPriceTxt($_item->getTaxAmount());
            $line[] = array(
                'text'  => $tax,
                'feed'  => 495,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
```

and the model `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice` and remove this

```
    // draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed'  => 495,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

Kindly open below file

```
/var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php
```

Find blow code

```
// draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed'  => 495,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );
```

and now comment this code. Problem resolved

Comment: You should never ever edit core files